# determine the continued fraction of $\sqrt{n^2 + 2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

determine the continued fraction of $\sqrt{n^2 + 2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

For rationals it is rather easy to do this and i know the algorithm, i only get stuck a lot by irrational number such as these. I tried this:

$\sqrt{n^2 + 2} = 1 + (\sqrt{n^2 + 2}) -1 = 1 + \frac{1- n^2}{1+\sqrt{n^2 + 2}}$. I almost get the form that i want, but the $n^2$ bothers me, how can i get rid of it?

Kees

Comment: Is there a way you can express the integral part of $\sqrt{n^2+2}$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: For integral $n\ge 1$, the integer part of $\sqrt{n^2+2}$ is $n$, but you used $1$.

Comment: do i need to split the cases when n=1 and when n > 1?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{n^2+2}-n = \frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+2}+n} = \frac{2}{2n+\frac{2}{n+\sqrt{n^2+2}}} = \frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n^2+2}}}$$
hence it follows that:
$$ \sqrt{n^2+2} = [n;\overline{n,2n}].$$
On the other hand, if $\alpha=[n;n,n,n,\ldots]$, we have $\alpha=n+\frac{1}{\alpha}$, from which $\alpha^2-n\alpha-1=0$ and $\alpha=\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}{2}$. If $\beta=[n,2n,n,2n,n,2n,\ldots]$, in a similar way $\beta=n+\frac{1}{2n+\frac{1}{\beta}}$, hence $\beta=\frac{1}{2}\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+2}\right)$, $\frac{1}{\beta}=-n+\sqrt{n^2+2}$ and $\sqrt{n^2+2}=[n;\overline{n,2n}]$ as stated before.

Comment: nice, is there a way to see directly that this fraction goes to n and 2n then to n then again to 2n instead of n,n,n,n,n,n?

Comment: *hence [it follows](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3235888)* - With that many kids being so afraid of math, it's no wonder that even Hollywood productions are trying to capitalize on the concept... :-$)$